# How get to a child of an optional field

Tags: typescript, type-conversion

I have this type:

```
export type GetWeeklyArticleQuery = {
    __typename?: 'Query';
    weeklyArticle?: {
        __typename?: 'WeeklyArticle';
        date: any;
        tags: Array<string>;
        title: string;
        authors: Array<{ __typename?: 'Author'; name: string; slug: string }>;
        bodyContent: { __typename?: 'RichText'; html: string };
        coverImage: {
            __typename?: 'Asset';
            url: string;
            title?: string | null;
            altText?: string | null;
            description?: { __typename?: 'RichText'; html: string } | null;
            caption?: { __typename?: 'RichText'; html: string } | null;
        };
        introLine: { __typename?: 'RichText'; html: string };
        footnote: Array<{ __typename?: 'RichText'; html: string }>;
    } | null;
};
```

In my code, I need to get the authors field
but I don't know how to type and manage it without create a custom type like Array<{ __typename?}. In my code I tried:

> let authors:weeklyArticleDto['authors'];

This gives me an error in my VS and in [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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):

```
type weeklyArticleDto = GetWeeklyArticleQuery['weeklyArticle'];
const weeklyArticle: weeklyArticleDto = data.weeklyArticle;
let authors:weeklyArticleDto['authors'];
if (weeklyArticle) {
    authors  = weeklyArticle.authors;
}
```

How can fix it?

Comment: You mention an error, but don't include the error in your question. Save people the time and effort of going to the external site and just include the text of the error message in the question. You might also use the text of the error message to search for duplicate questions, as I expect there are...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`NonNullable<Type>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) for this.

```
let authors: NonNullable<weeklyArticleDto>['authors'];
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)